# Remote Hyper-V Server from another computer

Tags: hyper-v

I have Hyper-V Server 2012 . Now i want connect to Hyper-V Server from my computer use Windows 7 but not in WorkGroup and connect to Hyper-V Server use ip or domain like this.

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihJ7z.jpg)

It's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Windows 7 simply does not know about all things that are available in Windows Server 2012 and beyond.

Refer this [Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794756(v=ws.10).aspx)